# Pycaret - Setting n_jobs in model_tune()

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-science, joblib, pycaret

I would like to use multiprocessing by specifying the `n_jobs` parameter in `sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV`

I would like to specify this through the `pycaret` wrapper in `pycaret.classification.tune_model`.

I have tried passing the `n_jobs` as `**kwargs`, but a `TypeError: ABCMeta object got multiple values for keyword argument 'n_jobs'`

How do I use all workers for my hyper-parameter tuning?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `n_jobs = -1` in `setup()`

[pycaret.readthedocs.io - Classification](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classification.html)

n_jobs: int, default = -1

> The **number of jobs** to run in parallel (for functions that supports
> parallel processing) **-1** means using **all processors**. To run all
> functions on single processor set **n_jobs** to **None**.

There is no `n_jobs` option in `tune_model()`

> tune_model(estimator, fold: Optional[Union[int, Any]] = None, round:
> int = 4, n_iter: int = 10, custom_grid: Optional[Union[Dict[str,
> list], Any]] = None, optimize: str = 'Accuracy', custom_scorer=None,
> search_library: str = 'scikit-learn', search_algorithm: Optional[str]
> = None, early_stopping: Any = False, early_stopping_max_iters: int = 10, choose_better: bool = True, fit_kwargs: Optional[dict] = None,
> groups: Optional[Union[str, Any]] = None, return_tuner: bool = False,
> verbose: bool = True, tuner_verbose: Union[int, bool] = True,
> return_train_score: bool = False, **kwargs) → Any

Here is a related SO question: [does-n-jobs-1-in-scikit-learn-use-all-cores-or-all-available-cores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75121051/does-n-jobs-1-in-scikit-learn-use-all-cores-or-all-available-cores?rq=2)